# Link only in the chapter names and the page in the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, hyperlink

I'm looking for a way to customize the table of contents, so that all the page numbers contain the link to go to the section indicated, but in addition to only the chapters can also be clickable, and the subsections are inactive, in the image I put an example of what I'm trying. Everything that comes out in blue should be clickable. I tried with the hyperref package but I can only leave to all the texts or the numbers or both, I could not reach that level of customization.

Thank you very much in advance, and sorry if it is something very simple to achieve, but I am a bit new in this world and looking in google I have not found anything similar that can help me.
[image: TOC links]

PS:
an example of the current configuration of the table of contents would be this, but it only allows me to have the number of the page with the link and in blue:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[hidelinks,pdfpagelabels,bookmarks,hyperindex,hyperfigures]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\hypersetup{
    linktoc=page,
    colorlinks=true,
    citecolor=blue,
    urlcolor=red,
    linkcolor=blue,
    citebordercolor={1 0 0},
    urlbordercolor={1 0 0},
    linkbordercolor={.7 .8 .8},
    breaklinks=true,
    }

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{One dummy example}
\lipsum[1-2]

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{One dummy example}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{One dummy example}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should add a small but complete example that allows to see which class you are using and how the table of contents is created.